# OCLint not in system path

Tags: ios, xcode, static-analysis, bash, oclint

I have an Xcode project. I tried to integrate `OcLint` in it. But it says there is no OCLint.How can I download and add`OCLint` to my system path so that I can integrate`OCLint` in my xcode project.

**EDIT:**

When I have a partof OCLint script as

```
hash oclint &> /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
echo >&2 "oclint not found, analyzing stopped"
exit 1
fi
```

It gives `oclint not found, analyzing stopped`.

Please give me a solution for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download oclint from : http://archives.oclint.org/nightly/oclint-0.9.dev.02251e4-x86_64-darwin-14.0.0.tar.gz

To integarte into your xcode project u could use this link :http://docs.oclint.org/en/dev/guide/xcode.html

Below is the script I am using to generate html file.

OCLINT_HOME is the path for oclint downloaded folder. I have renamed the folder to oclintrelease.

```
OCLINT_HOME=/Users/Dheeraj/Downloads/oclintrelease
export PATH=$OCLINT_HOME/bin:$PATH

hash oclint &> /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
echo >&2 "oclint not found, analyzing stopped"
exit 1
fi

cd ${TARGET_TEMP_DIR}

if [ ! -f compile_commands.json ]; then
echo "[*] compile_commands.json not found, possibly clean was performed"
echo "[*] starting xcodebuild to rebuild the project.."
# clean previous output
if [ -f xcodebuild.log ]; then
rm xcodebuild.log
fi

cd ${SRCROOT}

xcodebuild clean

#build xcodebuild.log
xcodebuild | tee ${TARGET_TEMP_DIR}/xcodebuild.log
#xcodebuild <options>| tee ${TARGET_TEMP_DIR}/xcodebuild.log

echo "[*] transforming xcodebuild.log into compile_commands.json..."
cd ${TARGET_TEMP_DIR}
#transform it into compile_commands.json
oclint-xcodebuild

fi

echo "[*] starting analyzing"
cd ${TARGET_TEMP_DIR}

oclint-json-compilation-database -v oclint_args "-report-type html -o $OCLINT_HOME/report.html"
```

Your report would be generated to the provided path in OCLINT_HOME using the above script.

If you want to generate report in your derived data folder then replace the last line with :

```
oclint-json-compilation-database -v oclint_args "-report-type html -o report.html"
```

HTML report would be generated if and only if your build is successful and you can check your generated report path and script report into Log Navigator of Xcode.

Comment: Is there a way to generate html report even if build fails?

Comment: if your project build is successful only then u can generate. if your oclint build fails then also html report is generated.

Comment: So it's like when we run oclint ,first errors are checked and if successfull it will build the project.Is it?

Comment: yes , it builds and generates report. if you don't have errors in your project i t would generate html report.

Comment: Some times OCLint is givinf empty results even if there are issues in code. What might be the reason?

Comment: It happens sometimes but just try cleaning the project and then again build it.

Comment: `xctool -workspace my.xcworkspace  -scheme OCLint -reporter json-compilation-database:compile_commands.json clean build`. This does clean and build as well. Only one project generates empty reports while another project creates proper report. Is this an issue with my project. I am using the same script in both the projects. From Xcode also the same.