# OCLint for Xcodebuild Shell Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, bash, xcode6, oclint

I am getting these error after creating a new Aggregate target with below script:

**error:**

```
oclint not found, analyzing stopped
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

Run Script Shell: /bin/sh

**Script:**

```
source ~/.bash_profile

hash oclint &> /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
echo >&2 "oclint not found, analyzing stopped"
exit 1
fi

cd ${TARGET_TEMP_DIR}

if [ ! -f compile_commands.json ]; then
echo "[*] compile_commands.json not found, possibly clean was performed"
echo "[*] starting xcodebuild to rebuild the project.."
# clean previous output
if [ -f xcodebuild.log ]; then
rm xcodebuild.log
fi

cd ${SRCROOT}

xcodebuild clean

#build xcodebuild.log
xcodebuild | tee ${TARGET_TEMP_DIR}/xcodebuild.log
#xcodebuild <options>| tee ${TARGET_TEMP_DIR}/xcodebuild.log

echo "[*] transforming xcodebuild.log into compile_commands.json..."
cd ${TARGET_TEMP_DIR}
#transform it into compile_commands.json
oclint-xcodebuild

echo "[*] copy compile_commands.json to the project root..."
cp ${TARGET_TEMP_DIR}/compile_commands.json ${SRCROOT}/compile_commands.json

fi

echo "[*] starting analyzing"
cd ${TARGET_TEMP_DIR}
oclint-json-compilation-database | sed 's/\(.*\.\m\{1,2\}:[0-9]*:[0-9]*:\)/\1 warning:/'
```

Do I have to change xcode default script to bash? How would I do it?

Comment: `oclint` is not in the `$PATH`.

Comment: @Roopesh Mittal: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30052686/oclint-not-in-system-path/

Answer (score 1):

You don't have OCLint in your path.
TO get OCLint in your path you can try removing

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

and replacing it with

```
OCLINT_HOME= **path to OClint downloaded and extracted folder**
export PATH=$OCLINT_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

you can try out this link for help :https://stackoverflow.com/a/30053104/3141464

Comment: I am able to build it by you solution, but I am not able to see the html report? Where can I find it?

Comment: u would be able to see your html report on the path you provided in last line for command oclint-json-compilation-database